# Strict compilation of XSLT, but without validating the input XML on application

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

I have a schema (as per previous questions, but this time it has some "required" attributes on FILLEDSQUARETYPE).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:complexType name="SQUARETYPE">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="contains">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="kind"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="FILLEDSQUARETYPE">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="contains">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="kind"/>

    <xs:attribute name="colour" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"  use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"  use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"  use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TRIANGLETYPE">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="contains">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="rotation" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="SQUARE">
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'FILLEDSQUARETYPE'" type="FILLEDSQUARETYPE"/>
    <xs:alternative test="@kind = 'SQUARETYPE'" type="SQUARETYPE"/>
    <xs:alternative type="xs:error"/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="TRIANGLE">
    <xs:alternative type="TRIANGLETYPE"/>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="rootShape">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
        <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have an XSLT that I can compile against this XSD, with 0 warnings.
Note it uses "element(tag,type)"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs msxsl"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:import-schema schema-location="MessingAbout.xsd"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SQUARE"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)">
    <foo>
      <xsl:value-of select="@colour"/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can apply that transform to xmls like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SQUARE x="1" y="2" width="234" kind="FILLEDSQUARETYPE" colour="red">
  <contains/>
</SQUARE>
```

and get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>red</foo>
```

HURRAY!

but...this is a simplification of my "real world" scenario.
In my real world scenario the source system is optimised to only export XML that's required by the transform, (and the schema describes a utopian world where all data is exported, with mandatory data, even if thats not required)

so, for example, the attribute "width", "x", "y" arent required by the transform, so would be excluded...like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SQUARE kind="FILLEDSQUARETYPE" colour="red">
  <contains/>
</SQUARE>
```

If we now apply the transformation (with SchemaValidationMode.Strict) to this XML then saxon will complain.

It will automatically validate the input.

```
Validation error on line 2 column 46
  FORG0001: Required attribute @Q{}y is missing on element <SQUARE>
  Validating /SQUARE[1]
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 4
Validation error on line 2 column 46
  FORG0001: Required attribute @Q{}x is missing on element <SQUARE>
  Validating /SQUARE[1]
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 4
Validation error on line 2 column 46
  FORG0001: Required attribute @Q{}width is missing on element <SQUARE>
  Validating /SQUARE[1]
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 4
Validation error on line 4 column 10
  XTTE1510: Three validation errors were reported. First error: Required attribute @Q{}y is
  missing on element <SQUARE>
```

Even though these errors are irrelevant to my XSLT, in my scenario this is a bit of an issue, ideally I'd like to turn off this behaviour, so that saxon doesnt try to validate things that are irrelevant to the execution of the XSLT.

Any ideas?

(I can obviously create a schema for the subset of data that IS exported, but this is actually quite onerous, and has nasty implications where effectively multiple types need to exist to describe effectively the same utopian data, when different subsets of children are exported.
I can also turn everything to optional, but this massively diminishes the value of the type check).

Comment: Which part is relevant, which part is irrelevant? Do you want to run the XSLT against the XML without validating the XML? How do you expect a template using a match pattern that uses schema types to be used if you don't validate? You can of course write templates matching based on the element name to be used and turn off validation but I don't see how you could use `match="element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)"` but expect it to work against invalid XML input.

Comment: yes I want to evaluate the XSLT against a non validated input. If the types are lazily evaluated whilst running the XSLT, and everything that is required to infer the types is present, the "element(SQUARE,FILLEDSQUARETYPE)" is valid i.e. the type system appears to be largely nominal, the only except is the use of "alternative", but I'd expect that to be evaluared in the obvious manner i.e. by evaluating the test clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea of telling the XSLT compiler about the schema is so that it knows what to expect when it sees the data; the compiler can generate code that makes assumptions about what the data will be like. If the data doesn't conform to the schema, then that negates the whole idea.

It's hard to be specific about exactly what would go wrong if invalid data were accepted, but the XSLT optimiser makes a lot of use of schema knowledge. To take a simple example, if your stylesheet does `<xsl:if test="exists(*)">`, and the schema says the element will always have children, then the XSLT processor might well have optimised that to "if true".

Comment: I think there is more value to type checking than just optimisation, I'm wondering if that optimisation can be turned off, and that types are evaluated lazily and inferred nominally from the schema, rather than validated eagerly. I'm trying to replicate a system that does just that. The code is compiled and type checked against the global schema, but the data is not read until run time, and only when its needed, if its not needed, then its not read, and if its not there then it doesnt matter.

Comment: its the type equivalent of the tree making a noise in the woods if noone is there to hear it.....for saxon the tree has to be demonstrably there...even if its existence is (logically) irrelevant to the transform. It feels like a form of incidental coupling.

Comment: I think my only option is to weaken the schema to make everything optional, then the input is always "correct", but at least I can detect invalid paths refering to things that arent in the schema

Comment: thanks for your help. I'll mark your answer as the answer....if I can turn the optimizer off and get around the issue, then let me know

Comment: actually just out of interest, XSLT now supports streaming, which I thought would have a similar issue?

Comment: There are quite a few optimizations you can turn off, but you can't for example change the basics of atomization, where the processor knows that if an attribute is typed as xs:integer then it's going to be an integer. I'm afraid schema-awareness isn't divisible in the way you would like. One thing you might attempt is to put all the schema-aware "as" attributes into shadow attributes (`_as="if ($SCHEMA_AWARE) then 'element(E, T) else 'element(*)'"`), develop your code with schema-awareness on, and then run it with schema-awareness off. Seems to be digging a deep hole, though.

Comment: I think making everything in the schema optional actually isnt as bad as I thought, what I'm really trying to detect is paths that can't exist. Do you know if its possible to get warnings if a section of XSLT code isnt "validated"?

Comment: I'll have a go and post this as a new question, I basically now have an end to end, that has value, its now about closing the holes